# Difference between using an abstract keyword for a method in interface vs not using the abstract keyword

Tags: java, interface, abstract

Say I have a Interface FirstInterface as follows :

```
  public interface FirstInterface {
    public void myInterfaceMethod();
}
```

Here I am declaring a method myInterfaceMethod() which will be defined in the class that will implement this Interface.

but I can also do

```
public interface FirstInterface {
    public abstract void myInterfaceMethod();
}
```

I have added a keyword abstract in the method declaration.
I want to know, if at all, does it make any difference to add a abstract keyword in the method declaration or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-default, non-static methods in interfaces are abstract by default. Adding the keyword is harmless, but changes nothing and is discouraged by the JLS "as a matter of style."

From [JLS§9.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> An interface method lacking a `default` modifier or a `static` modifier is implicitly `abstract`... It is permitted, but discouraged as a matter of style, to redundantly specify the `abstract` modifier for such a method declaration.